# How do I implement annotations in C?

Tags: java, c, linux, elf

I saw JNI uses these kinds of functions, but I don't know what it is:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_ClassName_MethodName
   (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
 {
     /*Implement Native Method Here*/
 }
```

What is "JNIEXPORT" and "JNICALL" in terms of c language feature?

Is it possible to create an annotation like this:

```
ROUTE("/test/whatever") 
void function(int x)
{
}
```

and make it valid C? I would need to be able to associate these annotations with the respective function at runtime somehow. Is there *any* way to do that? I know that it's possible to read out function pointers at runtime from an ELF file, so that part is done. Now I only need some way to annotate the functions. I don't care how ugly the implementation is, it only has to run on Linux.

Comment: `JNIEXPORT` and `JNICALL` are most likely macros. You can check what they are defined as by looking in the relevant .h file from the JNI SDK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JNIEXPORT` is a macro that evaluates to something like `__declspec(dllexport)`, depending on your compiler/platform. And `JNICALL` evaluates to the calling convention, i.e. `__stdcall` or whatever is appropriate for your compiler/platform.

As for the second part of the question, there is no runtime reflection capability in C and so no annotations.

Answer (score 2):

If you have time to spare and accept ugly, Linux specific, solutions you could also consider **customizing your GCC compiler** with [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org) extensions (MELT is a high-level domain specific language with a Lisp-like syntax to extend GCC) or with GCC plugins coded in C.

Customizing or extending GCC (or any other industrial-strength C or C++ compiler) takes time (weeks, not hours), because GCC is a very complex program. You have to understand GCC middle-end internal representations (notably *Gimple* and *Tree*-s) and passes, and both are complex matters. You can find some slides about MELT on [gcc-melt.org](http://gcc-melt.org/), and they give references and explanations about them.

You might customize GCC with e.g. pragmas or builtins for the [runtime reflection] annotation (and you would `#define` macros like your `JNIEXPORT` or `JNICALL` to use your pragmas or builtins); then you would have to extend GCC by e.g. adding a specific pass to handle your specific pragmas or builtins.